# Filter results of ManyToMany field in django

Tags: django, many-to-many

Hi I have a many 2 many field on a django object,

Foo <=> Bar

so if I filter by something like Foo.objects.filter(bar_*name*_contains='x')
I expect to get all Foo objects with related Bar objects having a name containing x,

So in the template I loop round Foos, then round foos bars, BUT I get ALL bars for that foo, not just the ones filtered by the filter!

Any help appreciated

---

Updated, some example code, a one to may for simplicity, same issue applies..

Models.py

```
class Foo(models.Model):  
    bob = models.CharField(max_length=255)  

class Bar(models.Model):  
    wibble = models.CharField(max_length=255)  
    foos   = models.ForeignKey('Foo')
```

So with the above objects I say something like...

```
foobar = Foo.objects.filter(bob__wibble__icontains='blagh')
```

I will pass to a template for rendering, and I expect to have all the foos with a bar matching the query, and ONLY the bars matching the query BUT I dont get that, I get all the foos with a bar matching the query AND every bar that has that foo as its Foriegn Key.

i.e. I have for one foo i have the bars [{'wibble':'blagh'},{'wibble':'blob'},{'wibble':twip'}]

I have the following in my template:

```
{% for bar in foobar.bar_set.all %}
    {{ bar.wibble }},
{% endfor %}
```

instead of just getting 'blagh,' i would get 'blagh,blob,twip'

Comment: Could you please provide some code?

Comment: you wanna make a filter in template??

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown any code, but it looks like you are filtering the Foo, not the Bar. So you get all Foos who have a Bar whose name is 'x' in amongst their list of bars, but you don't do anything to limit the Bars themselves to those that contain x.

You probably want to do it the other way round: use a filter expression on Bar to only get those where name='x', then iterate through the list of related Foos.

**Edit after comment** You still need to filter the Bars, not the foos. You can do the grouping in the template, when you iterate through. For example:

```
bars = Bar.objects.filter(wibble__icontains='blagh').order_by('foo').select_related()

{% for bar in bars %}
    {% ifchanged bar.foo %}{{ bar.foo.bob }}{% endifchanged %}
    {{ bar.wibble }},
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I need to group by Foos, not bars,  
I need the foos that have a bar matching, and then for each foo output the matching bars.

So I want to grab all this data without needing any messing about with SQL, sure a couple of minutes to do with SQL and placing it in dicts / dynamic objects but that negates the whole point of using Django objects..

Comment: I've added some more explanation in response to your comment.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I discounted that since I am in reality building the filters dynamically, and will have more than one many to one being filtered on i.e. foo.bar, foo.bob, foo.fred and every one of them needs to be restricted. , guess I will just bypass django objects again. I am shocked at how poorly thought through they are.